# Why doesn't html/template show all html conditional comments?

Tags: html, templates, go

I have a simple Go HTML template which contains HTML conditional comments:

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "os"
)

var body = `<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!--[if !IE]><!--><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script><!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if gte IE 9]><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script><![endif]-->

  </head>
</html>`

func main() {
    tmp := template.Must(template.New("tmp").Parse(body))
    tmp.Execute(os.Stdout, nil)

}
```

[This produces:](http://play.golang.org/p/iSnfpdfc0L)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>



  </head>
</html>
```

Why does [`html/template`](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Execute) remove those conditional comments after compiling?

Comment: I'm not familiar with go but I would guess you have to prepare the <>and" symbles. Also your first comment line has an accessive <!--> and the beginning and closing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since your question was *Why*, I will try to explain why comments are stripped away.

First of all, the purpose of the `html/template` package is to be *safe*. The [documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#pkg-overview) states:

> Package template (html/template) implements data-driven templates for generating HTML output safe against code injection.

This is done through context-sensitive escaping. In a [Golang-nuts thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/8y6by6SERyU) Kyle Lemons provide an example where conditional comments would currently break this safety unless the comments were stripped away:

```
<p>
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script><![endif]-->
{{.Stuff}}
<!--[if lt IE 9]></script><![endif]-->
</p>
```

In this case, any value in {{.Stuff}} will be executed as Javascript on some browsers and should therefore be escaped to be safe . This would require the template engine to be aware of this browser-specific interpretation of the comment, and any other non-standard behavior in all the browsers out there. This is not feasible.

Instead, `html/template` was designed to strip away any comments to ensure that the HTML it produces is safe from any injection attack.

**Workaround**

As mentioned by Dave, it is possible to use `template.HTML` to insert such comments. However, because of the security risk, the [documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#HTML) for `template.HTML` states (my emphasis):

> HTML encapsulates a known safe HTML document fragment. It should not be used for HTML from a third-party, or HTML with unclosed tags or *comments*.

Answer (score 10):

My workaround is to reimplement the **noescape** helper that was removed on commit [#938597eab997](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/detail?r=938597eab997)

```
funcMap := template.FuncMap{
    "noescape": func(s string) template.HTML {
        return template.HTML(s) 
    },
}
```

and then use it in your template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{{noescape "<!--[if lt IE 9]>"}}<html class="old-ie">{{noescape "<![endif]-->"}}
```

Comment: For completeness, since I stumbled across this... `myTemplate = template.Must(template.New(templateBaseName).Funcs(funcMap).ParseFiles(files...))`

Answer (score 1):

It looks that the problem was discussed on golang-nuts group:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/8y6by6SERyU/XQRnbw3aBhwJ

TL;DR
Go `html/template` strips of all html commments, and didn't interpret conditional comments since they are not a part of the standard.

Also the `{{noescape}}` directive has been removed: http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=3528

Comment: While `{{noescape}}` is removed, you can still using `template.HTML` to pass through strings you do not want altered: http://play.golang.org/p/JvFH5dUfmY

Answer (score 0):

Conditional commenting was only supported by Internet Explorer and isn't part of any standard that I can find.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment):

> Conditional comments are conditional statements interpreted by Microsoft Internet Explorer in HTML source code. Conditional comments can be used to provide and hide code to and from Internet Explorer.
>
> Conditional comments in HTML[1] first appeared in Microsoft's Internet Explorer 5 browser, although support has now been deprecated. In Internet Explorer 10 HTML conditional comments are not supported when the page is in standards mode (document mode 10)

Comment: I'm not using IE anywhere in a snippet. Neither serve the content through HTTP ;)

Comment: What browser are you using? Chrome and Firefox support *some* IE extensions for compatibility, but don't guarantee any of them. Go tries to follow the standards and probably strips anything outside of it.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Probably we will use different approach, but again - the question is about go, not a browser.

Comment: IE is only relevant here because conditional comments are an IE-only concept. The conditional comments just look like normal comments to `html/template`, and all comments are removed.

Answer (score 0):

adding a couple of examples of adding HTML comments to the html/template output:

1) adding comment using the HTML type:
http://play.golang.org/p/mYj4rxVfHW

2) using an added noescape function (which returns HTML):
http://play.golang.org/p/y61Hysfs3Y

Comment: StackOverflow questions and answers should include the relevant parts directly rather than relying on external links. Links such as play.golang.org should be used as an optional convenience for the reader, not as the sole means of getting at your answer (or question; I've edited this question to include the play contents as well).